# Spring Data call to Elastic search fails with parsing error

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a multiple mapping of several entities to the same index in order to reduce quota usage and store the related entities (but not extending each other, but just having related sense) under the same index. (i.e I just have set the same index name there:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
@org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document(indexName = "user", shards = 1, replicas = 0, refreshInterval = "-1")
public class Child implements Serializable {
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teacher")
@org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document(indexName = "user", shards = 1, replicas = 0, refreshInterval = "-1")
public class Teacher implements Serializable {
```

)

The data is stored correctly.

and the index itself is created correctly, but then I'm getting errrors when the SearchRepositories from the spring Data starting some search calls and I see the exceptions like this in my log:

```
mental-app_1            | 2019-08-21 14:52:06.572 DEBUG 11 --- [  XNIO-1 task-9] c.g.e.mental.web.rest.TeacherResource    : REST request to search for a page of Teachers for query aa
mental-app_1            | 2019-08-21 14:52:06.575 DEBUG 11 --- [  XNIO-1 task-9] c.g.e.m.service.impl.TeacherServiceImpl  : Request to search for a page of Teachers for query aa
mental-app_1            | 2019-08-21 14:52:06.585 ERROR 11 --- [  XNIO-1 task-9] c.g.v.s.jest.mapper.DefaultErrorMapper   : Cannot execute jest action , response code : 400 , error : {"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[query_string] query does not support [type]","line":1,"col":78}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[query_string] query does not support [type]","line":1,"col":78} , message : null
mental-app_1            | 2019-08-21 14:52:06.588 ERROR 11 --- [  XNIO-1 task-9] o.z.problem.spring.common.AdviceTraits   : Internal Server Error
mental-app_1            | 
mental-app_1            | com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.exception.JestElasticsearchException: Cannot execute jest action , response code : 400 , error : {"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[query_string] query does not support [type]","line":1,"col":78}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[query_string] query does not support [type]","line":1,"col":78} , message : null
mental-app_1            |   at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.mapper.DefaultErrorMapper.mapError(DefaultErrorMapper.java:30)
mental-app_1            |   at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.execute(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:1126)
mental-app_1            |   at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.execute(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:1116)
mental-app_1            |   at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.executeSearch(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:1229)
mental-app_1            |   at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.doSearch(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:1216)
mental-app_1            |   at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.queryForPage(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:414)
mental-app_1            |   at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.queryForPage(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:405)
mental-app_1            |   at com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate.queryForPage(JestElasticsearchTemplate.java:91)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.search(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:209)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
mental-app_1            |   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy212.search(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at com.github.eljah.mental.service.impl.TeacherServiceImpl.search(TeacherServiceImpl.java:110)
mental-app_1            |   at com.github.eljah.mental.service.impl.TeacherServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8264265.invoke(<generated>)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
mental-app_1            |   at com.github.eljah.mental.service.impl.TeacherServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ccdb394f.search(<generated>)
mental-app_1            |   at com.github.eljah.mental.web.rest.TeacherResource.searchTeachers(TeacherResource.java:162)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
mental-app_1            |   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
mental-app_1            |   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
mental-app_1            |   at org.zalando.logbook.servlet.NormalStrategy.doFilter(NormalStrategy.java:41)
mental-app_1            |   at org.zalando.logbook.servlet.LogbookFilter.doFilter(LogbookFilter.java:39)
mental-app_1            |   at org.zalando.logbook.servlet.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:31)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
mental-app_1            |   at com.github.eljah.mental.security.jwt.JWTFilter.doFilter(JWTFilter.java:38)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
mental-app_1            |   at org.zalando.logbook.servlet.SecurityStrategy.doFilter(SecurityStrategy.java:33)
mental-app_1            |   at org.zalando.logbook.servlet.LogbookFilter.doFilter(LogbookFilter.java:39)
mental-app_1            |   at org.zalando.logbook.servlet.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:31)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
mental-app_1            |   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SessionRestoringHandler.handleRequest(SessionRestoringHandler.java:119)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:364)
mental-app_1            |   at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
mental-app_1            |   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm using a custome ObjectMapper, could it be a root cause of the incorrect JSON sent to ElasticSearch? from the stacktrace I can't even imagine which side of client and server faces the parsing problems.

```
 public class CustomEntityMapper implements EntityMapper {

        private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

        public CustomEntityMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
            this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
            //objectMapper.writerWithView(Views.Elasticsearch.class);
            //objectMapper.readerWithView(Views.Elasticsearch.class);
            objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
            objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, true);
            objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, false);
            objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, true);
            //index.mapping.single_type
        }

        @Override
        public String mapToString(Object object) throws IOException {
            log.trace("Object to convert to JSON : {}",object);
            log.trace("Converting to json for elasticsearch >>> {}",objectMapper.writer().withView(Views.Elasticsearch.class).writeValueAsString(object));
            //log.trace("Converting to json for elasticsearch >>> {}",objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object));
            return objectMapper.writerWithView(Views.Elasticsearch.class).writeValueAsString(object);
            //return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
        }

        @Override
        public <T> T mapToObject(String source, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
            log.trace("Converting from json for elasticsearch <<< {}",source);
            return objectMapper.readValue(source, clazz);
        }
    }
```

Actually I'm using elasticsearch version 5.6.16 which still allows mapping of several types per one index.

And I don't know hase the Spring Data ElasticSearch confuigured the needed version of Jest client itself. I just passed the `<elasticsearch.version>5.6.16</elasticsearch.version>` in my pom.xml and not sure does it influence something or not.